# RESTAR O SUMAR VALOR A INPUT EN TIEMPO REAL JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cordial Saludo.

Les comento lo que quiero hacer, tengo un input con un valor x

```
<input type="text" value="17" id="Inventario">
```

y tengo varios input generados aleatoriamente:

```
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
```

Lo que quiero es si digito en el primero input 15, me lo reste al input principal de 17, osea, ese 17 se convierte en 2, y si borro el 15, vuelva a ser 17, asi con todos los input.

Espero me entiendan y me puedan ayudar.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.Can_Produc').keyup(function() {


    var importe_total = 0
      $(".Can_Produc").each(
        function(index, value) {
          if ( $.isNumeric( $(this).val() ) ){
          importe_total = importe_total + eval($(this).val());
                     }
        }
    );

          Inventario = $("#Inventario").val();
          INVENT_FINAL = parseInt(Inventario) - parseInt(importe_total);
          $("#Inventario").val(INVENT_FINAL);

    });

  </script>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var valor_inicial = $('#Inventario').val();

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.Can_Produc').keyup(function () {
        var valor = parseInt(valor_inicial);
        var valor_restar = 0;
        $('.Can_Produc').each(function () {
          if ($(this).val() > 0) {
            valor_restar += parseInt($(this).val());
          }
        });
            
        $('#Inventario').val(valor - valor_restar);
              
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="17" id="Inventario">

<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
```

Quizás resulte un tanto enrevesado, pero esto es lo que se me ha ocurrido. Lo que hago es almacenar el valor inicial del `input` principal (al que se le va a restar lo del resto de los `input`). Este valor nos resultará útil para cuando para calcular a que valor le tenemos que restar el contenido del resto de los `input`.

La base de la función es acumular el `value` de los input que van a participar en la resta en una sola variable para así restárserla al total inicial.

Comment: Voy a realizar las pruebas

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciono

Comment: Esto funcionaría si el valor del **input** principal no se puede modificar a mano, como me ha parecido entender. En caso de que ese valor si que se tuviese que modificar a mano habría que pensar en algo bastante más complejo.

Comment: Exacto, ese valor no se va poder modificar, estara disabled

Comment: Entonces estupendo ^^

Answer (score 4):

El valor inicial o el limite que nesecita lo e agregado en los atributos del input, el cual se obtiene para realizar la resta.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$('.Can_Produc').keyup(function() {

  var limite = parseInt($("#Inventario").data("limit"));
  var nuevo_valor =  $(this).val();
  var importe_total = 0;
  
  $(".Can_Produc").each(
      function(index, value) {
          if ( $.isNumeric($(this).val()) ){
            importe_total += parseInt($(this).val());
         }
      }
    );
    
    $("#Inventario").val(limite - importe_total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="17" data-limit="17" id="Inventario"><br/><br/>
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc"><br/>
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc"><br/>
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc"><br/>
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc"><br/>
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc"><br/>
```

Comment: Efectivamente me resta, el problema es que si quito la resta, lo que deberia hacer es sumarla: ejemplo:

Digite 2, el resultado es 15, cuando quito el 2, debe volver a 17

Comment: Te entiendo,actualizo la pregrunta y te aviso para que pruebes.

Comment: E actualizado el codigo.

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciono

Answer (score 3):

A pesar de haber recibido otras respuestas, he colocado una versión reducida utilizando `map` y `reduce` ya que esto te será funcional en situaciones más complejas o que contengan arreglos de mayor cantidad.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.Can_Produc').keyup(function() {
    
    let inv = $('#Inventario');
    
    // Obtener todos los inputs con la clase Can_Produc
    // utilizar get() para obtener el arreglo de los objectos input
    // y luego map para recorrer este arreglo y retornar solamente el valor del input
    let val = $('.Can_Produc').get().map(
        // Evaluar si el valor del input no es un numero (isNaN)
        // o si el input no tiene nada (length == 0)
        function(el){ return isNaN(el.value) || el.value.length == 0 ? 0 : parseInt(el.value)
      }).reduce(
        // Recorre el arreglo y va acumulando el valor del arreglo.
        function(anterior, actual) { return anterior + actual; 
      })
    
    // Asignar el valor
    inv.val( inv.data('limit') - val )
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="17" data-limit="17" id="Inventario"><br/><br/>
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc"><br/>
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc"><br/>
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc"><br/>
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc"><br/>
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc"><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

me tope con algo similar 
la logica es la siguiente
El TOTAL, tiene que estar almacenado en algun lugar, entonces puedes usar lo siguiente

```
<input type="text" value="17" data-limit="17" id="Total">
```

AL momento de llenar el input Adelanto, tienes que tambien llenar el data-limit

```
$("#Total").data("limit", valor Total)
```

una ves lleno podas acceder a ese valor para poder realizar la resta del valor sin modificar el temporal.

```
$("#Radelanto").keyup(function(e){
   if (e.target.value != "")  //en el if solo verifica cuando no haya nada en el input
      var a = parseFloat(e.target.value);
   else
      var a = 0;
   var actual = parseFloat($("#Total").data("limit"));//obtiene el valor temporal
   $("#Total").val(actual); // envias el valor temporal al input TOTAL
   var nuevo = (actual - a);  // realizas la resta
   $("#Total").val(nuevo); // envias el valor nuevo (la resta)
});
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiente el mismo ejemplo de tu codigo, solo le agregaría una comprobación si el total del importe es distinto a 0.

Si es cero devuelvo el valor por defecto del inventario.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="17" id="Inventario">

<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">
<input type="text" class="Can_Produc">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.Can_Produc').keyup(function() {


    var importe_total = 0
      $(".Can_Produc").each(
        function(index, value) {
          if ( $.isNumeric( $(this).val() ) ){
          importe_total = importe_total + eval($(this).val());
                     }
        }
    );

          Inventario = $("#Inventario").val();
          INVENT_FINAL = parseInt(Inventario) - parseInt(importe_total);
          $("#Inventario").val(INVENT_FINAL);
          
          if(importe_total == 0){
            $("#Inventario").val(17);
          }
          

    });

  </script>
```

Comment: El 17 puede ser variable, ya que viene de una BD, Pero no hace exactamente lo que quiero, pasa lo mismo que con la respuesta de Orlando